# Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I have a script where if you enter a certain command a channel will be deleted but it does not work And Counting does not go in MemberCount for some reason

Not working code

```
         const counter = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name ==="Counting")
         counter.delete();
```

Counting channel

```
 message.guild.channels.create("Counting", {
            type: "text",
            parent: message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name ===`┊ MemberCount: ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}` )
        });
```

MemberCount channel

```
message.guild.channels.create(`┊ MemberCount: ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`, {
            type: "category",
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                    deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                }
            ],
                position: 1
        });
```

The full code
https://pastebin.com/dR9sVysg
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: The channel named `Counting` does not exist at the time you're trying to find it in cache

Comment: Ok but what can I do then?

Comment: Please provide your full code using something like a Gist or Pastebin etc.

Comment: Channel names cannot be in uppercase , it can only be in lower case unless the type of channel is a voice , i don't know about a store or news channel because i don't know a developer license server not a verified or partnered server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just avoid the upper case error with the following code:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() ==="counting")
```

With this method the channel name will be defined no matter whether the name is upper case or lower case.